# How to use the --config or -c option in serverless while deploying?

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless

I have divided my apis into microservices and have a separate yml for each. I did this to resolve CloudFormation Resource limit error (Number of resources is greater than maximum allowed, 200). So now I have multiple serverless-[serviceName].yml files. The only problem now is that I need to rename them again and again when deploying (rename to serverless.yml).

I found a solution to this, i.e., to use `--config or -c Name of your configuration file, if other than serverless.yml|.yaml|.js|.json.` (https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/deploy/)

Now I am running the command `sis deploy -s stageName -f functionName -c serverlessFileName.yml` to deploy but it throws an error `This command can only be run in a Serverless service directory`.

This works perfectly if I run `sis deploy -s stageName -f functionName` and rename the file to deploy to serverless.yml.

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Serverless Version : 1.38.0

Nodejs Version : 10.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This flag `--config <filename>` was introduced in the [`1.45` serverless version](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/releases/tag/v1.45.0).

So, in order for this flag to work, you need to **update serverless**.

Comment: Yeah, I had figured that out. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in the Serverless Framework - but I think it's because you're passing `-f functionName` to `sls deploy`.

Try again, but remove `-f functionName`, as it's not needed on deployment (a deployment will deploy all functions declared in your `serverlessFileName.yml` file).